# Прямое присваивание значений полям записи в конструкции TList<record>

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Чтобы была понятна суть вопроса привожу упрощенный код:

```
type

  TMyRecord = record
    Field1, Field2, Field3: String
  end;

  TMyList = class(TList<TMyRecord>);

var
  MyList: TMyList;



procedure InputRecord;
var
  MyRecord : TMyRecord;
begin
  MyRecord.Field1 := '123';
  MyRecord.Field2 := '321';
  MyRecord.Field3 := '';
  MyList := TMyList.Create;
  MyList.Add(MyRecord);
  ...
  MyList.Items[MyList.Count-1].Field3 := '321'; 
  // В этом месте компилятор выдает: [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(44): E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to
end;
```

Собственно интересует вопрос, как-нибудь можно сделать редактирование одного этого поля, не перезаливая в TList запись целиком?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обращайтесь к свойству List:

```
MyList.List[MyList.Count-1].Field3 := '321';
```

---

Обратите внимание:

- метод List добавился в версии Delphi XE3. В более ранних версиях он отсутствует.
- метод возвращает "сырой" массив, количество элементов в котором равно `Capacity`, а не `Count`.